# net/http server does not send 100 Continue unless client sends Transfer-Encoding: chunked or nonzero Content-Length

Tags: http, go

I'm writing a HTTP server in Go that will receive requests from clients with a `Expect: 100-continue` header. However, it appears that the net/http server doesn't send a `HTTP/1.1 100 Continue` unless the client also sends a `Transfer-Encoding: Chunked` header, which some clients (for example, ffmpeg with an `icecast://` destination) do not.

Here's a minimal server, that writes into a `bytes.Buffer` (I've reproduced the same behaviour with a more complicated server that, for example, uses `io.Copy()` to write into a file):

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(writer http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        log.Printf("Expect header: %v\n", r.Header.Get("Expect"))
        log.Printf("Transfer-Encoding header: %v\n", r.Header.Get("Transfer-Encoding"))

        buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
        defer func() {
            log.Printf("Buffer size: %d\n", buf.Len())
        }()
        defer r.Body.Close()

        log.Println("Writing.")
        io.Copy(buf, r.Body)
    })

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3948", nil))
}
```

And here's a transcript of two HTTP conversations (via telnet), where the server sends a 100 in one but not in the other:

```
PUT /telnetlol HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Expect: 100-continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 18 Mar 2021 10:59:09 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

```
PUT /telnetlol HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Expect: 100-continue
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

test
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 18 Mar 2021 10:59:35 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
```

Is this a bug in Go, or am I misunderstanding the HTTP spec? The spec reads:

> Upon receiving a request which includes an Expect request-header field with the "100-continue" expectation, an origin server MUST  respond with 100 (Continue) status and continue to read from the input stream, or respond with a final status code. The origin server MUST NOT wait for the request body before sending the 100 (Continue) response.

**Edit:** Sending a non-zero `Content-Length` header in the initial request also makes the server reply with a `100 Continue`. (Although, if I understand the spec correctly, it should still reply with a Continue irregardless.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The net/http server correctly handles the request:

```
PUT /telnetlol HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Expect: 100-continue
```

with this response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 18 Mar 2021 10:59:09 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

The request does not have a message body per [RFC 7230 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3):

> The presence of a message body in a request is signaled by a
> Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding header field.

A server may omit sending the a 100 response when there is no message body per [RFC 7231 5.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.1.1):

> A server MAY omit sending a 100 (Continue) response if it has
> already received some or all of the message body for the
> corresponding request, or if the framing indicates that there is
> no message body.

In addition, the client request is bad per RFC 7231 5.1.1:

> A client MUST NOT generate a 100-continue expectation in a request that does not include a message body.

Comment: Good catch, thanks. Seems like both butt and ffmpeg violate the spec in that case...