# go http server doesn't send 100 continue

Tags: go, http, http-status-code-100

I have a service that collects and processes data (more precisely road traffic data in Datex2) from different governmental organizations.
I want to send a 100-continue with a Go http server to a client that sends a request with this header:

```
Content-Length: "4914"]
Content-Type: "application/xml"
Expect: "100-continue"
```

The client doesn't send authorization credentials with this request. It waits for the 100 to send a second request, which will contain the auth credentials.

I don't want to read the body of the first request, which would let to sending 100, because I first want to get the authorization credentials.

Here is one example of the codes i tried to use:

```
if c.Request.Header.Get("Expect") != "" {
    c.Writer.WriteHeader(http.StatusContinue)
    c.Writer.WriteHeaderNow()
    time.Sleep(30 * time.Second)
    return
}
```

In my understanding this should send the 100 immediately.
But I sends a response (200) when return is reached.
With reference to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66689843/net-http-server-does-not-send-100-continue-unless-client-sends-transfer-encoding), I send requests with different informations in the header, but nothing worked out..

**Edit:**
Here are sample client:

```
func main() {

    client := http.Client{}
    reqBody := []byte(`{"somekey":"somevalue"}`)

    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, "http://localhost:8080/somepath", bytes.NewBuffer(reqBody))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    req.Header.Set("Expect", "100-continue")

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusContinue {
        panic("invalid status code")
    } else {
        println("ok")
    }
}
```

and server:

```
func main() {
    server := http.Server{
        Addr:    "localhost:8080",
        Handler: http.HandlerFunc(Handle),
    }

    server.ListenAndServe()
}

func Handle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Header.Get("Expect") == "100-continue" {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusContinue)
        return
    }
}
```

I get response code 200.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand "But I sends a response (200) when return is reached" correctly, you're receiving a `200` code instead of a `100` at the client side.

I don't know what `c.Writer` is in your example, but you're probably invoking `ResponseWriter#Write` at some point. See the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ResponseWriter.Write):

> If WriteHeader has not yet been called, Write calls WriteHeader(http.StatusOK) before writing the data.

From my testing, the response code will also set to be `200` if you call `ResponseWriter#Write` *after* invoking `ResponseWriter.WriteHeader(StatusContinue)`.

So long story short: don't invoke `ResponseWriter#Write`. Since `c.Writer` seems to be some wrapper around the `ResponseWriter` (since that one doesn't have a `WriteHeaderNow` method), make also sure your wrapping library doesn't write anything to the response body either.

Comment: I edited the issue. Now there is no wrapper and I don't call 'Write', but still get 200.

Answer (score 0):

If the client set the `Expect: 100-continue` header, then the net/http server sends the `HTTP/1.1 100 Continue` response on first read of the request body.

Here's how to handle 100-continue in the handler:

```
 func example(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
     // Check request headers.  The handler must not read the
     // the request body while doing this.
     u, ok := auth(r)
     if !ok {
          // Auth failed, write header and exit.
          http.Error(w, "auth required", http.StatusForbidden)
          return
     }
     // Read the request body.
     // The net/http server sends 100-continue on the first
     // call to Read on the request body.
     err := r.ParseMultipartForm(10000)
     ...
}
```

Comment: With the first request the client doesn't send an auth header, because of this I don't want to read the body. Is there another way to send the 100?